# how to print an array in c according to if they are ascending and descending in different lines?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, recursion

I am trying to print the elements of an array in different lines according to if they are ascending or descending. for example I have an array: 
a[] = {3,5,6,8,4,2,-1,-3,6,5,4,1,3}; after I call the method printArr(a, sizeof(a), indexStart); the output should be:

```
3568
842-1-3
-36
6541
13
```

here is my code:

```
void printArr(int *a, int size, int index){
int i=index;
if(i==size)
    return;
printf("%d",a[i]);
if(a[i]<a[i+1]){
    while(a[i]<a[i+1] && i<size){
        printf("%d",a[i+1]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
else{
    while(a[i]>a[i+1] && i<size){
        printf("%d",a[i+1]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
printArr(a,size,i);
}
```

here is my main:

```
int main()
{
int a[] = {3,5,6,8,4,2,-1,-3,6,5,4,1,3};
printArr(a,13,0);
return 0;
}
```

when I run it (CodeBolcks) I get the following input:

```
3568
842-1-3
-36
6541
1370
```

where did the 70 at the end come from? 
when I compile it in Linux(terminal) I get the following :

```
3568
842-1-3
-36
6541
1332767
```

where did the 32767 at the end come from? how can I fix my code? 
I have to use loops and recursion.

Comment: `printArr(a, sizeof(a), indexStart);` : `sizeof(a)` --> `sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i` range check is wrong.

fix like this

```
void printArr(int *a, int size, int index){
    int i=index;
    if(i>=size-1)
        return;
    printf("%d",a[i]);
    if(a[i]<a[i+1]){
        while(i<size-1 && a[i]<a[i+1]){
            printf("%d",a[i+1]);
            i++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    else{
        while(i<size-1 && a[i]>a[i+1]){
            printf("%d",a[i+1]);
            i++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printArr(a,size,i);
}
```

Comment: What if `size=1` and `index=0`?

Comment: @Arash Nothing is displayed. In this program, it is expected that the length of the sequence is 2 or more.